# What car has a hood badge with T in an Elipse with a slash through it?

Tags: vehicle-identification

Today I spotted a car with a hood badge I didn't recognize (actually it was on the grille but grille badge sounds wrong).

The badge was a broad ellipse with a T inside it, and a diagonal slash cutting across the left arm of the T.

This is my attempt to draw it from memory.  Google image search wasn't able to recognize it from this.

[image: Unknown hood badge]

The car was black and looked quite modern.  It was possibly a largish hatchback with sleek looking lines.  Maybe a large coupe or a midsize sedan with an unusally smooth transition between the cabin and trunk. I didn't get a good look at the back end. Beyond that nothing really stood out about it other than the hood badge.

I saw it on the street in Victoria, British Columbia, Canada.

Comment: Sorry, I know this isn't exactly on topic, but it seemed the best SE site for the question.

Comment: Looks very much like the Talbot badge.  But then that wouldn't be a modern car.  Talbot was swallowed by Chrysler in the 1980s.

Comment: Any idea of colours? shape of car? what country?

Comment: Tata, Tesla or possibly Mahindra?

Comment: @Zaid, maybe I misremembered a Tata or Mahindra badge enough to get what I got but "T with a a slash across the left arm" is what I specifically remember noting about it at the time I saw it.  It wasn't a Tesla as I recognize that logo.

Comment: It's not the new [Kia](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0229/9049/products/Kia_emblem_Main_54392733-8cd1-4ce8-b513-f00dc876981f_1024x1024.jpg?v=1435353211) logo, right?

Comment: @JPhi1618 No I hadn't seen that before, but that's not it.

Comment: Could it be a TVR? I've seen a few logos that have a union jack overlaid. Could  the badge be from an aftermarket tuning house or limited model rather than the manufacturer. For example Toyota TRD.

Comment: @Peter It didn't look anywhere near as exotic as any TVR I've seen.  An aftermarket tuning badge does seem to be the most likely explanation.  It also means it will probably be really hard to find a conclusive answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I was able to come up with is this Daewoo badge:

[image]

It is the closest thing I could find which comes close to your description.

Answer (score 0):

What about Ifiniti (Nissan)?  It's not really a T though...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't ring any bells, so I agree with your comment that its probably a tuning badge. Alternatively, did you see an Opel or Hyundai badge in passing and see these slightly differently?

Hyundai: [image: Hyundai badge]

Opel: [image: Opel badge]